# Combines two arrays into one sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I'm new in javascript and I don't know how to merge some array. I want to reverse word manually but I mess up. It's my code:

```js
function reverseString(kata) {
  let currentString = kata;
  let newString = '';
  let cetakKata = '';
  for (let i = kata.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newString = newString + currentString[i];
  }
  console.log(newString);

  const splitNewString = newString.split(' ')
  console.log(splitNewString);

  for (let i = 0; i < splitNewString.length; i++) {
    const cetak = splitNewString[i].split('').reverse().join('')
    cetakKata = cetakKata + cetak
  }
  console.log(cetakKata);
}
reverseString('hello java script');
```

my output:

```
scriptjavahello
```

output I want:

```
script java hello
```

Comment: Why do you clone `kata` char-by-char? To then split it at spaces (and at the end combine them without the spaces)?

Comment: `'hello java script'.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

```
function ReversedStringSentence (stringData) {
  return stringData.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}

ReversedStringSentence("I am Greater everyday")
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse without `.reverse()`

```js
reverseString('hello java script');

function reverseString(kata) {
  let splited = kata.split(' ');
  let reversed = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < splited.length;i++) {
    reversed.push(splited[(splited.length - 1) - i ]);
  }
  let stringReversed = reversed.join(' ');
  console.log(stringReversed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wants to learn javascript and that's why you're doing it like you do, but there are already functions that does what you're trying to do.

```
arr.reverse() // reverses array
```

I don't know how many programming languages that you have learned, but what works best for me is to just read through all documentation so I know what kind of options I have at hand. I won't remember it all, but I will recognize them when I have to search for solutions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

```js
function reverseString(kata) {
  const AT_SPACE = ' ';
  
  return kata
  .split(AT_SPACE)
  .reverse()
  .join(AT_SPACE);
}

let reversedKata = reverseString('hello java script');
console.log(reversedKata)
```